# Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream from IOHandler.ReadStream

Tags: delphi

I was trying to display the sent textfile to memo.lines with out saving it to a disk

from server

```
  try
  Ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Ms.LoadFromFile('update.txt');
  Ms.Position := 0;

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Ms, 0, True);
  finally
    Ms.Free;
  end;
```

to client...im not sure how to do this in client

```
  try
   Ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
   Ms.Position := 0;

   IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
   IdTCPClient1.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(Ms, -1,false);

 finally
   Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(Ms);
   Ms.Free;
 end;
```

can anyone help me on how to make this work if its possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, you simply forgot to reset the stream's `Position` property back to 0 before calling the Memo's `LoadFromStream()` method:

```
IdTCPClient1.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(Ms, -1,false);
Ms.Position := 0; // <-- add this
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(Ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

**If I were you, I would still buffer the read data because of two reasons:**

- **The network stream is unidirectional and non-positionable** therefore not really file like. (Yes, it also means, that you must refresh it manually/programmatically every time some new data is received.)
- **If the connection fails the read buffer could be filled with gibberish** which gets diplayed, because You have no further means to control what gets displayed once you redirected the input of your memo.

If you do not want to save the sent data to disk, you could still save it to a *TMemoryStream* instance, which could be used as a parameter of the memo's *.LoadFromStream()* method.